# Efficiently initialize 2D array of size n*m in Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and am trying to create 2D integer arrays of a known and fixed size. How can I do this?

The arrays I have in mind are the Python-provided `array.array`, although I am not averse to using a library like NumPy.

I know this can be done via lists, but I want to use an array since they are much more space efficient. Right now, I am initializing lists in this way, but I want to replace it with an array:

`my_list = [[ 0 for _ in range(height) ] for _ in range(.width)]`

For example, in C, I would write

`int my_array[ width ][ height ];`

How can I do this in Python

Comment: are you open to using numpy?

Comment: So, what **exactly** do you mean by array? `numpy.ndarray`? Or `array.array`?

Comment: Please post a minimal example.  What is the actual data type?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?

Comment: An array.array. I am not averse to using NumPy. I'll update my original question; thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.zeros([height, width])
```

For example:

```
>>> np.zeros([3, 5])
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Note that if you specifically need integers, you should use the `dtype` argument

```
>>> np.zeros([3, 5], dtype=int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: @tpepin96 yes, they are. Although, given the dimensions you are talking about, even an list of lists wouldn't be an issue on modern hardware.

Comment: @tpepin96 They are primitive arrays, so each element is whatever size the `dtype` implies...

Comment: @tpepin96 `scipy.sparse` exists for cases that are *actually* large (1000x1000 is not)

Answer (score 3):

The numpy equivalent of the code you posted is:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.empty([height, width])
```

`empty` reserves uninitialized space, so it is slightly faster than `zeros`, because `zeros` has to make sure that everything is initially set to 0.

Note that, like in C/C++, you should write values before reading them, because they initially "contain garbage".

Docs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html